# jquery event listener for detect clicks dynamically?

Tags: jquery, addeventlistener

I have 2(or more) tables with different ids and class names within each tables are same. Depending on which span is clicked I want to show or hide rows within tbody. for eg: if the span class="quarter" is clicked, I want to show the row with class="quarter" within tbody and hide the class="month". Should I use jQuery event listeners to achieve this? I want this code to be resuable to many other tables with id=tab3 or tab4 and possibly many more. So I do not want to use $("#tab1").onclick...I want to be able to detect which span within which table was clicked and then show the tbody elements within it.

```
<table id="tab1">
<thead><tr><th><span class="quarter">Quarter</span></th></tr>
<tr><th><span class="month">Month</span></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="quarter"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="month"><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table id="tab2">
<thead><tr><th><span class="quarter">Quarter</span></th></tr>
<tr><th><span class="month">Month</span></th></tr>
```

Final Solution(my actual html structure is little different from the example above)

```
$('table thead span label').click(function() {  
                        $("label:not(this.className)").css('color','#d6c9b9');      
                        $(this).css('color','#00425f');         
                        $(this).parents('table').parents('table').find('table').hide();                     
                        $(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr').hide();
                        $(this).closest('table').show();                        
                        $(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr.' + this.className).show();
                        $(this).parents('table').parents('table').find('table.'+ this.className).show();
            });
```

Comment: The solution I have involves heavy usage of table names hard-coded. Looking to make the code dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('span').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr').hide();
   $(this).closest('table').find('tr.' + this.className).show();
})
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `var c = this.className` as there is no need for jQuery in that line of code or better yet, just use `$(this).closest('table').find('tr.' + this.className).show()` without using `var c` at all.

Comment: Nice ! Didn't know about $.closest(); +1

Comment: Making every span listen to a click event may cause trouble with any other unintended closest table rows?

Comment: My html structure was little more complicated than the example I gave above. So the following code helped me achieve the correct functionality with inspiration taken from your answer.

Comment: couldnt post the code here, posted above along with the question

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table thead span').click(function() {
   $(this)
       .closest('table')  // find parent table
       .find('tbody tr.' + this.className)  // detect row with same class name
       .show() // show that row
       .siblings('tr')  // capture other tr
       .hide(); // hide those tr
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/326/)**

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
$('.toggle thead tr').click(function(){
    var c = $(this).find('span').attr('class');
        p = $(this).parent().parent();
    p.find('tbody tr').hide();
    p.find('tbody .' + c).show();
});

<table id="tab1" class="toggle">
...
</table>
```

**DEMO : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bS55H/)**